# How to calculate speech time in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to calculate the time for a speech with javascript. I now have two functions, one to get the number of words in a text area, and one to display a number of seconds as `hh:mm:ss`. I am unable to merge the two functions. (Info: one takes 1 minute on a speech with 120 words.)

```
    /* Word Count */

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Counting Words</title>
    <script> 
        function countWords() { 
  
            // Get the input text value 
            var text = document 
                .getElementById("inputFieldSpeech").value; 
  
            // Initialize the word counter 
            var numWords = 0; 
  
            // Loop through the text 
            // and count spaces in it  
            for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) { 
                var currentCharacter = text[i]; 
  
                // Check if the character is a space 
                if (currentCharacter == " ") { 
                    numWords += 1; 
                } 
            } 
  
            // Add 1 to make the count equal to 
            // the number of words  
            // (count of words = count of spaces + 1) 
            numWords += 1; 
  
            // Display it as output 
            document.getElementById("show") 
                .innerHTML = numWords; 
        } 
    </script> 
    <script>
    function eraseText() {
    document.getElementById("inputFieldSpeech").value = "";
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "";
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <textarea id="inputFieldSpeech" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
    <button onclick="countWords()"> Count Words </button>
    <br>
    <p>Word Count: <span id="show">0</span> </p>
    <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="javascript:eraseText();">

     /* Seconds to HH:MM:SS */
   
    <script>
    var timestamp = 120;
    var hours = Math.floor(timestamp / 60 / 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(timestamp / 60) - (hours * 60);
    var seconds = timestamp % 60;
    var formatted = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="totalTime"></p>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("totalTime").innerHTML = (formatted);
</script>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `numWords = text.split(/\w+/).length - 1;`

Comment: First step: make the time calculation a function. Second Step, call it

Comment: Why are there 4 separate script blocks!